# Time slice a netcdf file over multiple date ranges

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a 3 dimensional netcdf file (time, lat, lon) in which I would like to time slice over multiple date ranges. Slicing over one continuous range is doable, like this.

```
start_date = dt.datetime(2017,6,1,0)
end_date = dt.datetime(2017,8,31,0)

yyyy = dt.datetime.strftime(start_date,'%Y')
data_g = xr.open_dataset("/cfsr/data/"+yyyy+"/g."+yyyy+".0p5.anl.nc")

g = data_g['g'].isel(lev=15)
g = g.sel(time=slice(start_date1,end_date1))
```

This keeps my netcdf file three dimensional, but now only includes data from June of 2017 through August of 2017. Now, for example, say I wanted to include from October of 2017 through November of 2017. Is this something that is possible? The end goal is to take the mean of all the data which would span different time slices over different years. I know I could do this manually by creating a bunch of individual arrays (g1, g2, etc..) but I figured there might be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another slice and use [`xarray.concat`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html) to combine the two subsets, like:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_onedeg/Best')
temp_var = ds.Temperature_isobaric.sel(isobaric6=100000)

g1 = temp_var.sel(time=slice('2020-04-28', '2020-04-30'))
g2 = temp_var.sel(time=slice('2020-05-06', '2020-05-07'))
combined = xr.concat([g1, g2], dim='time')
```

Comment: What exactly would the variable time be in this case? When I try and concat them together using g1['time'], I get: ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 730 on <this-array> and length 365 on 'time'

Comment: I've updated my example code to correct a typo (time -> 'time'), and to be fully self-contained. Essentailly, you need to give it a dimension name for `time`, not an array.